# Insert foreign key in db hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, foreign-keys

**I have a node db with five pieces of data:**

- id (int, PK)
- question (varchar)
- result (varchar)
- left_id (int, FK)
- right_id (int FK)

**and two foreign keys in the same table:**

- left_id -> id
- right_id -> id

**here is my bean:**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "node")
public class Nodes
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    @NotNull
    private int id;

    @Column (name = "question")
    private String question;

    @Column ( name = "result")
    private String result;

    @OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="left_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Nodes left;

    @OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="right_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Nodes right;
```

**I can view left_id by:**

```
nodes.getLeftNodes().getId_node();
```

But I can't insert a new data left/right_id in my db

My insert method is

```
public void insert_question(String question, int left_id) throws HibernateException
    {
        try
        {
            Session session = getSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Nodes node = new Nodes();

            node.setQuestion(question);
            node.setId_node(left_id);

            session.saveOrUpdate(node);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
        }
```

The question is inserted in a database but not left_id. To me, the problem is that foreign key (Node left or right) is a object but in my db left_id is a integer !

**How can i insert left/right_id in db without left/right_id integer because there are a foreign key ?**

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a new node, containing a reference to an existing left node. And `left_id` (which I'll rename `leftId` to comply with the standard naming conventions), is the identifier of the existing left node.

So it's quite simple: you first need to get a reference to the existing node left node in the database, the create your new node referencing this left node, the insert your new node:

```
Node leftNode = (Node) session.load(Node.class, leftId);

Node node = new Node();
node.setQuestion(question);
node.setLeft(leftNode);

session.save(node);
```

Note that I also renamed `Nodes` to `Node`. An instance of this class represents *one* node, so there's no reason to name this class `Nodes`.

Comment: Thank you for your aswer. I try your solution and i have this error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.create(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lnet/sf/cglib/proxy/MethodProxy;"